# How to implement optional multiple same fields in django modelForm of a model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have the following models in django:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
address = models.ManyToManyField(Address, symmetric=False)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

class Address(models.Model):
address= models.TextField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.address
```

and the model form:

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields='__all__'
```

Profile can have multiple addresses i.e, user should be able to add multiple addresses in a single form. How do I implement this?

```
name: _______________
address: ______________
address: ______________
address: ______________
```

Comment: Your model, as is, does not satisfy `Profile can have multiple addresses`. I would suggest having `Profile.address' be a m2m relation to an address model.

Comment: @CoffeeBasedLifeform Updated.

Answer (score 1):

You need formsets. Here is the django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/) explaining it and a good [tutorial](https://whoisnicoleharris.com/2015/01/06/implementing-django-formsets.html)